# QList<struct> and memory leak

Tags: c++, struct, memory-leaks, removechild, qlist

I have a structure like this:

```
    struct MatInfo
   {
       cv::Mat mainImgMat;
       cv::Mat roiMat;
       CvRect roiRect;
       int lineId;
       bool doProcess;
       QString plateString;
       CvRect finalRect;
       float cnf;
    };
```

I want to have a Qlist of this struct which appends member in a slot like this:

```
    addToList(Mat m, Mat ocrMat, CvRect plateRect, int lineId, bool doProcess)
   {
        if (_lst_MatInfo.size() < 30 && !ocrMat.empty())
        {
            MatInfo info;
            info.mainImgMat = m;
            info.roiMat = ocrMat;
            info.roiRect = plateRect;
            info.lineId = lineId;
            info.doProcess = doProcess;

            _lst_MatInfo << info;

       }
    }
```

then the members of the Qlist will be processed and freed in another thread like this:

```
    ocr()
    {
        MatInfo matInfo = _lst_MatInfo.first();
       _lst_MatInfo.removeFirst();
       process(matInfo);
    }
```

notice that i dont new anything and every time i use the MatInfo , I remove the first member of the Qlist.
but the memory leaks and the app stops working.
should I do anything more than removeFirst()?

Comment: A memory leak (as bad as it is) will usually not immeadiatly stop a program working. Anyway, please provide a [mcve]!

Comment: It does not immeadiatly stop the program working. the program stops after a few minutes

Comment: So provide a MCVE then (please read the link above). Your code snippets don't compile, and you don't call `addToList` anywhere.

Comment: it was obvious i think. each time the image arrives from the device(camera), addToList is called.

Comment: Please read again what an [mcve] is (and why it is required if you expect any help)